# How can I display the reason for <a4j:status> error?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm currently debugging an annoying AJAX bug in our web application using JSF2 and RichFaces v4.5.12.Final where I need further information about the reason why an ajax update fails.

We generate rather complex forms with several elements and on some of these forms the following code snippet fails to re-render and sets  to error.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myBean.value}">
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@form" render="@form,messages" status="minimal" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

The AJAX status is displayed using the following code:

```
<a4j:status name="minimal" onstart="$('body').css('cursor', 'progress');" onstop="$('body').css('cursor', 'default');">
    <f:facet name="start">
        <h:graphicImage name="/3rd-Party/Fugue-Icons/hourglass.png"  styleClass="middle" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="stop"></f:facet>
    <f:facet name="error">
        <h:graphicImage name="/3rd-Party/Fugue-Icons/exclamation-red.png" styleClass="middle" />
    </f:facet>
</a4j:status>
```

**Is there any way to display the reason why the render fails? Can I access any variable containing some kind of error message?**

Debugging shows that the execute is performed and doesn't result in any server side errors. The error happens on client side where the AJAX fails to reload the page content. It doesn't matter if we use `render="@all"` or anything else... the error occurs on some of our pages. Others with the same `<a4j:ajax>` work normally.

Comment: `<a4j:ajax ... render="@this" />` works... but nothing with more scope.

Comment: Figured out that `<a4j:ajax ... render="@parent" />` works... but that's not enough since other elements on the same page need to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error handler is triggered when there is a problem with the server response. RichFaces has [<a4j:log>](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Processing_management-log) specifically for debugging, it will at least tell you what kind of error it is.

Comment: Thanks... but the LOG seems weird... starts with `info [10:16:44.299]: Received 'begin' event from <select id=pageCreator:cmbx_186053852_field ...>` and `info [10:16:44.980]: Received 'beforedomupdate' event from <select id=pageCreator:cmbx_186053852_field ...>` and then says `info [10:16:44.980]: Server returned responseText: <?xml ...` with content and finally says `warn [10:16:44.981]: richfaces.queue: ajax submit error: An empty response was received from the server. Check server error logs.` which clearly is not true.

Comment: Looks like that kind of response is unexpected... other elements which work show different logs.

Comment: AH! By formatting that XML response I've seen that the response doesn't seem well-formed. Looks like RichFaces fails to parse it. It includes some inline javascript code which may be broken. I'll try to isolate it.

Comment: RichFaces doesn't parse the response, JSF does. Try debugging jsf.js, that's where the message comes from ("An empty response …").

Comment: Thanks again... `<a4j:log>` helped me out. We had broken tags in the response which the browsers quietly ignore... but the ajax javascript failed because of it. We've fixed that code and now the ajax render works.